# bulky insert record to database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert approximatlly 10 records.I am thinking foreach loop,do u think is it the best way to do that.whenn searching what is the best method to do that,I find something like this,

```
GO
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
SELECT 'First' ,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second' ,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third' ,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fourth' ,4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fifth' ,5
GO
```

what is the differences between the this and foreach loop.which one is the better.
thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
VALUES ('First',1),
('Second',2),
('Third',3),
('Fourth',4),
('Fifth',5)
GO
```

Both the `foreach` loop and the `union all` methods would be what is called "Row by Agonizing Row" approach

Comment: "Row by Agonizing Row" means what??

Answer (score 1):

Just Create a single for inserting all the record..
Because foreach loop will hit the database  10 times and u will take more time and resources..

So better to make single query for all the 10..

```
INSERT INTO Table ( FirstCol, SecondCol) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have MSSQL 2008 or later, you can use multi-valued insert:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name)  
VALUES (1, 'One'),
       (2, 'Two'),  
       (3, 'Three')
```

Unfortunately, this syntax is not supported by MSSQL 2005 and earlier.